# What values does Camera.Parameters.set("picture-size", ?) take?

Tags: android, camera

my app involves some work with the camera, therefore it needs to handle capturing of images with different resolution. My targets are 1.6 - onwards. Does anyone know what to pass in the value argument for

```
Camera.Parameters.set("picture-size", value)
```

I have look at the Donut release of the Camera app, however, it was not very clear what exactly has been used there as the value is retrieved from the SharedPreferences.

`// Set picture size parameter.
String pictureSize = mPreferences.getString(CameraSettings.KEY_PICTURE_SIZE,
                                    getString(R.string.pref_camera_picturesize_default));
mParameters.set(PARM_PICTURE_SIZE, pictureSize);`

Lookin at the strings.xml I can see that `R.string.pref_camera_picturesize_default = 2048x1536`, however, I'm not sure what other values can be passed there? Is it any resolution you fancy, or are they only certain resolutions the drivers can handle? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the way I'd handle it is two-fold:

- For Android 2.0 (API 5) and newer, use `Camera.Parameters` and its `getSupportedPictureSizes()` method to find out what the available options are for the hardware you're running on
- For Android 1.6, I'd just leave the size alone

I'd use reflection or conditional class loading to have a single code base that supported both paths, choosing the right one for the device it ran on.